# Flutter/Dart - Convert image(base64) show error in circle avatar

Tags: flutter, dart

Convert the image get in to :

```dart
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
var image = ((prefs.getString('photo'))); 
var send = {'name': usu, 'email': email, 'image': photo};
```

In widget:

```dart
Widget _buildDrawer(BuildContext context) { return FutureBuilder<Map>(
      future: getFutureDates(), // function where you call your api
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {
    if(!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      Uint8List profile = base64.decode(snapshot.data['image']); new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: new Text((json.encode(snapshot.data['name']).toString().replaceAll('"', ''))),
                  accountEmail: new Text((json.encode(snapshot.data['email']).toString().replaceAll('"', ''))),
                  currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: MemoryImage((profile)),
                  ),
                ), } }
```

The Name and email is ok, but Photo give me a error:

> Invalid character (at charact
>   er 5)
>
> data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBw8PDw8PDxAPDw4PD...

Comment: Please, update title and text. It is hard to take in your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason:

base64 string contains  `data:image/png;base64,` cause error

```
data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBw8PDw8PDxAPDw4PD
```

Solution: 
remove string `data:image/png;base64,` , you can use `substring(22)` and only keep

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBw8PDw8PDxAPDw4PD...
```

code snippet

```
void main() { 
  String base64str = '''data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBw8PDw8PDxAPDw4PD''';
  String newString =  base64str.substring(22);      
  print(newString);

}
```

output

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBw8PDw8PDxAPDw4PD
```

Comment: Bad Solution. What if the image type is JPEG?.
A better solution will be `base64str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,'), '')`